# Neo4j: Import data from CSV (PostgreSQL) do not commence

Tags: csv, neo4j

I want to move one table with self reference from PostgreSQL to Neo4j.

PostgreSQL:

```
 COPY (SELECT * FROM "public".empbase) TO '/tmp/empbase.csv' WITH CSV header;
```

Result:

```
$ cat /tmp/empbase.csv | head
e_id,e_name,e_bossid
1,emp_no_1,
2,emp_no_2,
3,emp_no_3,
4,emp_no_4,
5,emp_no_5,3
6,emp_no_6,2
7,emp_no_7,3
8,emp_no_8,1
9,emp_no_9,4
```

Size:

```
$ du -h /tmp/empbase.csv
631M    /tmp/empbase.csv
```

I import data to neo4j with:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
> LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/tmp/empbase.csv" AS row
> CREATE (:EmpBase:_EmpBase {     neo_eb_id:      toInt(row.e_id),
>                                 neo_eb_bossID:  toInt(row.e_bossid),
>                                 neo_eb_name:    row.e_name});
```

and this works fine:

```
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 20505764
Properties set: 61517288
Labels added: 41011528
846284 ms
```

The Neo4j console says:

```
Location:
/home/neo4j/data/graph.db
Size:
5.54 GiB
```

But then I want to proceed with the relation that each `emp` has a `boss`. So simple emp->bossid SELF reference.
Now I do it like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/tmp/empbase.csv" AS row 
MATCH (employee:EmpBase:_EmpBase    {neo_eb_id: toInt(row.e_id)})
MATCH (manager:EmpBase:_EmpBase     {neo_eb_id: toInt(row.e_bossid)})
MERGE (employee)-[:REPORTS_TO]->(manager);
```

But this works for 5-6 hours and breaks in the end with system failures it freezez the system.
I think this might be terribly wrong.

**1. Am I doing sth wrong or is it bug for No4j?**

**2. Why out of 631 MB csv now I get 5,5 GB?**

**EDIT1:**

```
$ du -h /home/neo4j/data/
20K /home/neo4j/data/graph.db/index
899M    /home/neo4j/data/graph.db/schema/index/lucene/1
899M    /home/neo4j/data/graph.db/schema/index/lucene
899M    /home/neo4j/data/graph.db/schema/index
27M /home/neo4j/data/graph.db/schema/label/lucene
27M /home/neo4j/data/graph.db/schema/label
925M    /home/neo4j/data/graph.db/schema
6,5G    /home/neo4j/data/graph.db
6,5G    /home/neo4j/data/
```

SOLUTION:

1. Wait until the `:schema` in console says ONLINe not `POPULATING`
2. change log size in config file
3. Add `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000` in second csv import
4. Index only on `label`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only match on one Label: `MATCH (employee:EmpBase   {neo_eb_id: toInt(row.e_id)})`

Did you create the index: `CREATE INDEX ON :EmpBase(neo_eb_id);`
then wait for the index to get online `:schema` in browser

**OR** if it is a unique id: `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:EmpBase) assert e.neo_eb_id is unique`;

Otherwise your match will scan all nodes in the database for each MATCH.

For your second question, I think it's the transaction log files,
you can limit their size in `conf/neo4j.properties` with

`keep_logical_logs=100M size`

The actual nodes and properties files shouldn't be that large. Also you don't have to store the boss-id in the database. That's actually handled by the relationship :)

Comment: He also seems to have forgotten periodic commit in the second load csv.

Comment: Shall the  `periodic commit` be applied to the relationship load csv?

Comment: 2. The `bossid` is the field in postgreSQL table. 
What is the best way to get rid of it in the neo4j db and to store it in relation only?

Comment: match (n:EmpBase) remove n.neo_boss_id